# Programatically discover a ServiceHost's Service Type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicehost, servicecontract

G'day,

I've tried searching MSDN and here, but I don't think I can do this:

Given a reference to a `ServiceHost`, is it possible to discover the type of the host it is executing?

Something like

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyContractImplementation));
Type serviceType = host.MagicCallHere();
Assert.True(typeof(MyContractImplementation) == serviceType);
```

Does MagicCallHere exist?

Bonus marks if you can dodge reflection...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check check the Descriptions servicetype property:

```
var serviceType = host.Description.ServiceType
```

Answer (score 3):

Check as below :

```
typeof(ServiceContract) == host.Description.ServiceType
```